# Combining overloaded operators with 'new' object

Tags: c++, object, pointers, dynamic

i'd like to ask something rather difficult for me; I have to make a calendar-type program, but with an overloaded '+=' operator.

So it goes like this:

```
template<typename T1,typename T2,typename T3> //int,int,int
class T_sort_data{

T1 p1;
T2 p2;
T3 p3;

public:

    T_sort_data(){
        cout << "\n\t Constructed at [" << this << "]\n";};

/   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const T_sort_data& obj) // get function
{
    os << "\nDay : " << obj.p1 << " \n";
    os << "Month : " << obj.p2 << " \n";
    os << "Year : " << obj.p3 << " \n";
    return os;
}*/

void set_date(){
    int dd,mm,yy;
    cout << "\n\n\tPlease input the day, the month and the year : \n\n";
    cin >> dd >> mm >> yy;
    p1 = dd;
    p2 = mm;
    p3 = yy;
}

// validator here, which works ...  

T_sort_data<int,int,int>& operator+=(const T_sort_data<int,int,int>& second)
{
    p1+=second.p1;
    return *this;
}

friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, T_sort_data& obj) // set function
{
    is >> obj.p1;
    is >> obj.p2;
    is >> obj.p3;
    return is;
}

~T_sort_data(){
    cout << "\n\t Deconstructed [" << this << "]\n";};

  };

  int main(){
T_sort_data<int,int,int> * a = new T_sort_data<int,int,int> ;
bool more = true;
    string answ;

a->set_date();
//cin >> a; (this doesn't work)
    //validator goes here

//a += a; (this, again, doesn't work)

delete a;

return 0;
  }
```

Whenever I make an object using  "T_sort_data a;" those operations work fine, but whenever I use "T_sort_data * a = new T_sort_data;"
shit hits the fan.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you using raw pointers? C++ code should not have any raw pointer, except if you are implementing the back-end of a container, for example. C++ variables lifetime is based on RAII. If you want to share a object instance, use smart pointers or references instead, never raw-pointers. Raw-pointers equals to potential bugs, Memory-leaks, and unreadable API interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post exactly what is going wrong so I have to infer that from the code.

The issue that you're running into is that overloaded operators work on instances or references to objects, not on pointers to objects. In the cases where your code doesn't work, you're dealing with *pointers* to objects. So, in order to use your overloaded operators, you need to dereference the pointer (effectively turning it from a pointer pointing to a value into the value itself) before applying the operator, for example:

```
cin >> *a;
```

or

```
*a += *a;
```

Comment: erm...yeah. that was actually what i needed. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

`T_sort_data a` is a variable of type `T_sort_data`.

`T_sort_data * a` is a variable of type pointer to `T_sort_data`.

Your overloaded operators expect their operands to be of type `T_sort_data`, not pointer to `T_sort_data`. Use the unary `*` operator to dereference the pointers, so that the operand types are what the operators expect.

This is pretty fundamental. Here's the same thing with `int` and `std::cout`: http://codepad.org/N07Xckdy